# Exploring a MySQL database with R and dplyr

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

I just received an export from a MySQL database as a file mydb.sql.  I installed MySQL in my Mac OS 10.10 laptop, put the .sql file in "/usr/local/mysql/data/", started the MySQL server.  In R I installed the packages dplyr, RMySQL and their dependencies.  I tried the dpylr function:

```
src_mysql(dbname = "mydb.sql")
```

as well as a few variations on this, but I get the error

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'mydb'

What am I missing?

Comment: you didn't (1) create a database (2) import the SQL into the database (3) use `src_mysql` properly. The entirety of which is beyond help in a single SO question.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a database first, then import the data.  Then the dplyr command works fine.  [This helped](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/import-a-mysql-database-into-os-x-10-6-via-terminal/). If you are familiar with MySQL, this question probably annoyed you.  R developers might find this more useful.